# Error: invalid address or ENS name with Chainlink VRF

Tags: hardhat, chainlink

Smart Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol"; 
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";

contract KartoCarsNFT is ERC721A, Ownable, VRFConsumerBaseV2 {

    event RequestSent(uint256 requestID, uint32 numWords); 
    event RequestFulfilled(uint256 requestID, uint256[] randomWords, uint256 payment); 

    struct RequestStatus {
      uint256 paid; 
      bool fulfilled; 
      uint256[] randomWords; 
    }

    enum SaleStatus {
      PAUSED,
      WHITELIST,
      PUBLIC
    }

    using Strings for uint256;

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Set Sale as PAUSED on DEPLOY ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SaleStatus public saleStatus = SaleStatus.PAUSED;

    string private preRevealURI;
    string private postRevealBaseURI;

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Sale Settings ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    uint256 public PRICE_KC = 0.07 ether;
    uint256 private constant MAX_KC = 10000;
    uint256 public publicPerWallet = 3;
    uint256 public wlPerWallet = 3; 

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Chainlink Settings ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    uint256[] public requestIds; 
    uint256 public lastRequestId; 
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 100000; 
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3; 
    uint32 numWords = 2; 
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

    address[] private teamAddress;
    uint[] private teamSplit;

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Chainlink Sub ID ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    uint64 s_subscriptionId;

    bytes32 public whitelistMerkleRoot;

    mapping(address => uint256) public wlMintedAmt;
    mapping (address => uint256) public publicMintAmt; 
    mapping(uint256 => RequestStatus) public s_requests; 

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Reveal ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    bool public revealed;
    uint256 public tokenOffset;

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Chainlink VRF ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    bytes32 public chainlinkKeyHash;


    constructor(
      address[] memory _team,
      uint[] memory _split,
      string memory _preRevealURI,
      address _vrfCoordinator,
      bytes32 _chainlinkKeyHash,
      uint64 _subscriptionId
    ) 
      ERC721A("Karto Cars NFT", "KARTOCARS") 
      VRFConsumerBaseV2(0x271682DEB8C4E0901D1a1550aD2e64D568E69909) { 
        addTeam(_team, _split);
        preRevealURI = _preRevealURI;
        chainlinkKeyHash = _chainlinkKeyHash;
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(_vrfCoordinator);
        s_subscriptionId = _subscriptionId;
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Prevent Bots ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    modifier callerIsUser() {
      require(tx.origin == msg.sender, "The caller is another contract");
      _;
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Metadata Functions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function setPreRevealURI(string memory _URI) external onlyOwner {
      preRevealURI = _URI;
    }

    function setPostRevealBaseURI(string memory _URI) external onlyOwner {
      postRevealBaseURI = _URI;
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Token URI ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Before reveal, return same pre-reveal URI
    // After reveal, return post-reveal URI with random token offset from Chainlink
    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
      require(_exists(_tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
      if (!revealed) return preRevealURI;
      uint256 shiftedTokenId = (_tokenId + tokenOffset) % totalSupply();
      return string(abi.encodePacked(postRevealBaseURI, shiftedTokenId.toString()));
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Sale State Function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    function setSaleStatus(SaleStatus _status) external onlyOwner {
      saleStatus = _status;
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Setting Merkle Root Function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function setMerkleRoots(bytes32 _whitelistMerkleRoot) external onlyOwner {
      whitelistMerkleRoot = _whitelistMerkleRoot;
    }

    function processMint(uint256 _quantity) internal {
      require(msg.value == PRICE_KC * _quantity, "INCORRECT ETH SENT");
      require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_KC, "MAX CAP OF KC EXCEEDED");
      _mint(msg.sender, _quantity);
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Whitelist Sale Function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function whitelistSale(uint256 _quantity, bytes32[] memory _proof) external payable callerIsUser {
      require(saleStatus == SaleStatus.WHITELIST, "WL SALE NOT ACTIVE");
      require(
        MerkleProof.verify(_proof, whitelistMerkleRoot, keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender))),
        "MINTER IS NOT ON WHITELIST"
      );
      require(_quantity <= wlPerWallet, "SURPASSED WL TX LIMIT"); 
      require(_quantity + wlMintedAmt[msg.sender] <= wlPerWallet , "MAX WL MINTED");
      wlMintedAmt[msg.sender]+= _quantity; 

      processMint(_quantity);
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Public Sale Function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function publicSale(
      uint256 _quantity
    ) external payable callerIsUser {
      require(saleStatus == SaleStatus.PUBLIC, "PUBLIC SALE NOT LIVE");
      require(_quantity <= publicPerWallet, "QUANTITY SURPASSES PER-TXN LIMIT"); 
      require(_quantity + publicMintAmt[msg.sender] <= publicPerWallet, "MAX PUBLIC MINTED"); 
      publicMintAmt[msg.sender]+= _quantity; 
      processMint(_quantity);
    }

  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Airdrop Function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  function airDrop(
    uint256 _quantity, address _receiver 
  ) public onlyOwner {
    _mint(_receiver, _quantity); 
  }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Edit Chainlink Configuration ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function setChainlinkConfig(bytes32 _keyhash) external onlyOwner {
      chainlinkKeyHash = _keyhash;
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Request Token Offset ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // NOTE: contract must be approved for and own LINK before calling this function
    function startReveal(string memory _newURI) external onlyOwner returns (uint256 requestId) {
      require(!revealed, "ALREADY REVEALED");
      postRevealBaseURI = _newURI;
      requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
              chainlinkKeyHash,
              s_subscriptionId,
              requestConfirmations,
              callbackGasLimit,
              numWords
          );
      return requestId;
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ CHAINLINK CALLBACK FOR TOKEN OFFSET ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 _requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
      require(!revealed, "ALREADY REVEALED");
      revealed = true;
      
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ onlyOwner Functions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function changePrice(uint256 _price) public onlyOwner {
        PRICE_KC = _price; 
    }

    function changePublicAmt(uint256 _amt) public onlyOwner {
        publicPerWallet = _amt; 
    }

    function changeWhitelistAmt(uint256 _wlAmt) public onlyOwner {
        wlPerWallet = _wlAmt; 
    }

    function numberMinted(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {
      return _numberMinted(_owner);
    }

    function getOwnershipData(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (TokenOwnership memory) {
      return _ownershipOf(_tokenId);
    }

    function addTeam(address[] memory _team, uint[] memory _split) public onlyOwner {
        require(_team.length == _split.length, "Address and Shares must equal"); 
        teamAddress = _team; 
        teamSplit = _split; 
    }

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Withdraw Functions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    function internalWithdrawal(uint _amount) internal onlyOwner {
        for(uint i = 0; i < teamAddress.length; i++) {
            uint split = teamSplit[i]; 
            (bool os, ) = payable(teamAddress[i]).call{value: _amount * split / 100}(''); 
            require(os);
        }
    }

    function teamWithdraw() public onlyOwner {
        internalWithdrawal(address(this).balance); 
    }

    function emergencyWithdraw() public onlyOwner {
        (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}(''); 
        require(os);
    }
}
```

Deploy Script:

```
async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners(); 
    vrfCoordinator = 0x271682deb8c4e0901d1a1550ad2e64d568e69909; // SET FOR MAINNET, WILL NEED TO CHANGE TO TESTNET IF WANTED TO TEST FOR ALL 3.
    chainlinkKeyHash = 0x8af398995b04c28e9951adb9721ef74c74f93e6a478f39e7e0777be13527e7ef;
    subID = 0x67388e9228301fce52e39196537fa6a6ee0a1f91;

    console.log("Deploying contract with the account: ", deployer.address); 
    
    console.log("Account Balance: ", (await deployer.getBalance()).toString()); 

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("KartoCarsNFT"); 

    console.log("Deploying Contract...Stand by....");
    
    const token = await Token.deploy([0x8faA2802aACa47AEe59f02A96E29225436eEF9A8,0x012D8E2cE2716B260718abE39062A76be15570B3],[98,2],"test",vrfCoordinator, chainlinkKeyHash, subID);

    console.log("Contract deployed to: ", token.address); 
}

main()
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error); 
    process.exit(1); 
});
```

We aren't sure if we are doing something wrong in our deploy script or if the contract needs to be setup different.

We have tried changing the addresses by putting them in quotes or wording the deploy script differently, but still nothing. The constructor at the top is where we are setting everything and our deploy script is setting the values for the constructor.

Comment: Carl, its not clear what error you're getting. Can you please update the question and be specific about your workflow that produces the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.